# Different ChartStyle for PieChart3D

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, visualization

I want to make a 3D PieChart with multiple layers of 3 different ChartStyles like this:

`PieChart3D[{{5, 12, 27}, {5, 5, 6, 1, 9, 14, 4}, {5, 12, 27}},
 LabelStyle -> {Green, Bold, 16},
 ChartStyle -> {{Red, Yellow, Blue},{Black, Green},{Cyan, White}}]`

but the specified ChartStyle doesn't work this way, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PieChart3D` chart style documentation says "With both row and column styles the last style may override earlier ones."  So some processing needs to be done on the data.

```
data = {{5, 12, 27}, {5, 5, 6, 1, 9, 14, 4}, {5, 12, 27}};
chartstyles = {{Red, Yellow, Blue}, {Black, Green}, {Cyan, White}};

d2 = Unitize[data] /. (1 -> 0);
d4 = Flatten /@ Array[(d3 = d2; d3[[#]] = data[[#]]; d3) &, Length[d2]];
c2 = Flatten[MapThread[Take[Flatten[
       ConstantArray[#2, Ceiling[Length[#1]/Length[#2]]]],
      Length[#1]] &, {data, chartstyles}]];

PieChart3D[d4, LabelStyle -> {Green, Bold, 16}, ChartStyle -> c2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris ! Another small problem, do you know ... When you pull a slice out from the PieChart, how do you save the pulled-out plot without using the right-click GUI tool ?